# Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: asp.net

```
    protected void CustomersGridView_DataBound(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            decimal rowTotal = Convert.ToDecimal(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "DC_No_Decimal"));
            if (e.Row.DataItemIndex >= inderGrid.PageIndex * inderGrid.PageSize && e.Row.DataItemIndex < inderGrid.PageIndex * inderGrid.PageSize + inderGrid.PageSize)
            {
                grdTotal = grdTotal + rowTotal;
            }
        }
        else if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer && inderGrid.PageCount == inderGrid.PageIndex + 1)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < inderGrid.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                decimal currentRowCellVal = Convert.ToDecimal(inderGrid.Rows[i].Cells[3].Text);
                grdTotal += currentRowCellVal;
            }
            e.Row.Cells[3].Text = grdTotal.ToString("c");
        }
        else if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
        {       
                e.Row.Cells[0].Text = "Totals:";
                // for the Footer, display the running totals
                e.Row.Cells[3].Text = grdTotal.ToString("0.00");
                // e.Row.Cells[2].Text = quantityTotal.ToString("d");        
                e.Row.Cells[1].HorizontalAlign = e.Row.Cells[2].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
                e.Row.Font.Bold = true;
        }
   }
```

The purpose of this grid is to display total in the final page of the grid. When I'm going to the page page I get an error:

> Input string was not in a correct format.

In the final page of the grid I need total of all pages in the grid of cell[3]

Comment: Your question is not in a [correct format](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints). Closing... Ah and by the way, what is your question?

Comment: Hi Raj, can you update your question to give us a bit more info on where the problem is, and at least ask a question dont just put a title.

Comment: Can you please tell us the line at which the exception thrown? or if you can attach exception screenshot with the code mentioned?

Comment: Exception Details: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

Answer (score 1):

You say your error is in:

```
e.Row.Cells[3].Text = grdTotal.ToString("0.00");
```

You have to use a formatter:

```
e.Row.Cells[3].Text =  String.Format("{0:C}", grdTotal);
```

or

```
e.Row.Cells[3].Text = grdTotal.ToString("C", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Check if grdTotal is a decimal...

have a look at: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)

Comment: i m getting error in this place decimal currentRowCellVal = Convert.ToDecimal(inderGrid.Rows[i].Cells[3].Text);

Comment: What is de ''value'' in inderGrid.Rows[i].Cells[3].Text?

Comment: inderGrid.Rows[i].Cells[3].Text= amount field

Comment: @RajKumar: yes, obviously it's an amount field - but could that string be *empty*, by any chance?? Or contain something that **isn't** really a decimal number??

Comment: @Ray it is a string, use the debugger and see what is in the string. If it is a numeric value, which is is not, you where not asking for our help, because it would run fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is with this line

```
e.Row.Cells[3].Text = grdTotal.ToString("0.00");
```

I am assuming your grdTotal variable is a decimal here, Using "0.00" isnt a valid formatter.

Check out the MSDN site here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.tostring.aspx

At the very least you can try `e.Row.Cells[3].Text = grdTotal.ToString();`

Comment: i m getting error in this place                                        decimal currentRowCellVal = Convert.ToDecimal(inderGrid.Rows[i].Cells[3].Text);

Comment: Do you know what the value of what you are trying to convert to decimal is?   Also I cant remember if that will work if the value you try convert is null or empty string, or just has some letters.  Look into decimal.tryparse then only assign the value if the parse is a success

Comment: cells[3] contain numeric value ie., amount field

Comment: @RajKumar did you try using TryParse?